# Usando a variável global __dirname no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa noite pessoal!! alguém consegue da um help aí, preciso sair da pasta back-end e entrar na front-end e pegar o meu arquivo html usando o  __dirname conforme está na imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite pessoal, conseguir resolver!!

`server.get("/", (req, res) => {

var path = require('path')
    res.sendFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '../../front-end/src/views/index.html'))`